# scheduler using multithreaded programming

Tags: c++, multithreading, runtime-error

I wrote the following code to implement a round-robin scheduler. 
How the code works: I ask the user to **enter the process name**(a floating point number which will be used to identify the process) and the **process burst time**(total time for which the process runs) **after pressing 'p'**. There are **two queues**: a **job** queue which always contains the currently running process(i.e. it always contains only one process) and a **ready** queue which contains all other processes.There is **no waiting queue** here so that the code is not too complex. A **timer is implemented using time(NULL)** function and multithreading. whenever the user enters a new process, it is put into ready queue and rrscheduler is called.

*If a process was already running and 'p' is pressed, then rrscheduler continues that process after adding the new process to ready queue(However, the timer was started again). Otherwise, the front process in the ready queue is started.*

returnname()-> returns the name of the process in the front of queue
peek()-> returns the time left for the process in the front of queue to complete 
deletecell()-deletes the front process of the queue
append()- adds a process to the end of a queue

*Each process in a queue is characterised by its name and time left.*

Even when the queues are empty, peek() returns 0 which is used to check if queue is empty.

Code:

```
  queue<float> job(0);
  queue<float> ready(0);
  queue<float> waiting(0);
  char c;
  time_t quantum;
  time_t quantrem, timerem;
  pthread_t thread1=0;

  /////////////////////////////////////////////////
  struct arg  //this is the argument passed to the timer function
 {
 time_t  time1;
 float name1;
 time_t quantum1;
 };
  //////////////////////////////////////////////////

 void* timer(void *);

 void rrscheduler(queue<float> &ready, queue<float> &job)
 {

 if(thread1!=0)  //when 'p' was pressed, another process was executing
   pthread_cancel(thread1);

 thread1=0;

 if(job.peek()==0 && ready.peek()!=0)   //if there are no processes currently running or the process' time or quantum has finished
 {
   cout<<"on the front end of ready queue is process "<<ready.returnname()<<endl;
   float a=ready.peek();
   float b=ready.returnname();

   ready.deletecell(); //remove a process ffrom ready queue and put it in job queue
   job.append(a,b);
   cout<<"Process "<<b<<"left the ready queue and joined the job queue"<<endl;
 }

 arg arg1;
 arg1.time1=job.peek();
 arg1.name1=job.returnname();
 arg1.quantum1=quantum;

 pthread_create(&thread1, NULL, timer, (void*)(&arg1)); //call the timer function thread


 }//rrscheduler ends

 ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////

 void* timer(void *argum)
 {

 arg *arg1= (arg*)argum;
 cout<<"PROCESS "<<arg1->name1<<" HAS ENTERED THE TIMER"<<endl;
 time_t d, timejob;
 d=arg1->quantum1 + time(NULL);
 timejob=arg1->time1 + time(NULL);

 while((quantrem=d-time(NULL))>0 && (timerem=timejob-time(NULL))>0)
 {
     //execute till either the process time or the process quantum gets finished
 }
 if(timerem>0)
 {
   cout<<"Time quantum finished for "<<arg1->name1<<endl;
   job.deletecell();
   cout<<"JOB DELETED"<<endl;
   ready.append(timerem, arg1->name1);
 }
 else
 {
   cout<<"Process "<<arg1->name1<<" finished"<<endl;
   job.deletecell();
 }

 rrscheduler(ready, job);
 }

 ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

 int main()
 {
 cout<<"Enter time quantum"<<endl;
 cin>>quantum;
 cout<<"Press p for entering a new process "<<endl;

 while(1)
 {
   c=cin.get();

   switch(c)
   {
   case 'p':

   if(thread1!=0)  //if when 'p' is pressed, another process was executing
   {
    float n = job.returnname();
    job.deletecell();
    job.append(timerem, n);
    pthread_cancel(thread1);
   }

   thread1=0;
   cout<<"Enter the process number and time"<<endl;
   float a, timeini;
   cin>>a >>timeini;
   ready.append(timeini, a);
   rrscheduler(ready, job);

   break;

   default:
   break;
   }//switch ends here

 }//while finishes
 }//main finishes
```

[image]

The process goes into while loop after the output 'PROCESS 1 HAS ENTERED THE TIMER' and blocks at the output 'Time quantum finished for 3.99296e-34'.

What am i doing wrong that it results in a segmentation fault and why is the process name being displayed as 3.99296e-34?

If anybody wants to see the queue header file it is [here](http://textuploader.com/?p=6&id=yvubs)

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: arg::name1 is defined as float, so what else should it be shown as? where exactly do you get a segfault (gdb will show you that)?

Comment: May be this would come in handy http://floating-point-gui.de/

Comment: Why on earth are you using a floating point number to identify the process? That's ringing a lot of alarm bells. If you must have identifiers of the form _xxx.yyy_, then either use a pair of integers in a struct, or a string.

Answer (score 2):

`arg::name1` is defined as float, so what else should it be shown as? You don't show the definition of `returnname`, but since `job.returnname` is assign-compatible, I assume this already also returns a float or something convertible.

You can find out where you got a segfault by running the program under gdb:

```
gdb your-program
```

You should compile your program with -g first, of course.

Comment: @nyarlathotep...name1 is of course a float value but it is entered by the user and is of the form of natural numbers.I am not changing it. So, how did it change to 3.99296e-34. Further returnname() definition is given in the header file, which i provided link to.